# Encrypted Time Machine backup is super slow using an encrypted USB volume?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, encryption

I have an external USB3 disk connected to my MacBook Pro. I first formatted it with GUID/APFS and encryption, and used the "atto disk benchmark" app to measure performance. It showed about 100MB for read/write.

Then I turned to Time Machine, and selected that volume as encrypted backup drive.

But Time Machine writing the backup is super slow. It takes about 100 seconds for 1 **megabyte** to be written. Thing is running for 20, 30 minutes by now, and I see 17 MB out of 112 GB of progress. It is so slow that Time Machine won't even give me a "time remaining" information.

Is there anything I am missing? Or should I just forget about using such kind of drive for an encrypted backup? (Doing an encrypted backup is a hard requirement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments by user [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) and this [apple community entry](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7813232) the "answers" are:

- Yes, a full disk encrypted TM backup to a USB3 drive is slow. Overall performance varies greatly, many small files need much more time compared to fewer large files. Overall, my 126 GB backup took about 12 hours.
- The one thing that you *can* (and should) take care: format the *whole* disk as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, **Encrypted**)". If you don't select **Encrypted**, TM will *later* encrypt the drive on its own, which requires (again!) plenty of time (*besides* the time it took to just write the backup itself). My initial approach of using APFS: don't do that!

Note: the one other thing I learned: you can easily suspend that first TM backup, simply by clicking the "skip this backup" menu item while it is running.

Comment: My TM on Mojave is not encrypted (and I would be annoyed if it was) - the point you made was that the TM disk has to be HFS+ and nor APFS

Comment: Updated the answer to make that more explicit.